# why JDBC gives error "undefined function SOUNDEX in expression"

Tags: java, jdbc

I am developing a database application in Java. I want to use `SOUNDEX()` function of SQL, but when I try to do this, I get an error reporting "undefined function `SOUNDEX()` in expression". Is it really undefined?

My query is as follows:

```
SELECT * from students WHERE SOUNDEX(studentName) = SOUNDEX('ali');
```

Answer (score 4):

This is not an issue with JDBC, but with the database server you are using. As far as I see, only MSSQL supports the `SOUNDEX` function. So if you are using MySQL, Derby or an other database server, you are unable to use it. Which one do you use?

To verify that this is a database problem and not a JDBC problem, you can manually connect to the SQL server and then try to perform the query.